# Generator expressions versus filter

Tags: python, performance, optimization, filter, generator

Giving the two following functions:

```python
list_of_dict = [{"x": i, "y": -1} for i in range(1_000_000)]

def tuple_comprehension_next():
    return next(x for x in list_of_dict if x["x"] == 50_000)

def filter_next():
    return next(filter(lambda x: x["x"] == 50_000, list_of_dict))
```

I noticed a significant difference in execution time.

```text
$ %timeit tuple_comprehension_next()
1.92 ms ± 87.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

$ python -m memray run tuple_comprehension_next.py
Start time: 2022-08-03 21:04:29.338000
End time: 2022-08-03 21:04:29.656000
Total number of allocations: 540
Total number of frames seen: 55
Peak memory usage: 286.4 MB
Python allocator: pymalloc
```

```text
$ %timeit filter_next()
3.22 ms ± 90.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

$ python -m memray run filter_next.py
Start time: 2022-08-03 21:03:52.530000
End time: 2022-08-03 21:03:53.044000
Total number of allocations: 542
Total number of frames seen: 55
Peak memory usage: 286.4 MB
Python allocator: pymalloc
```

I don't understand why the generator expressions is that much faster.

Looking at the bytecodes using `dis.did` did not help there is obviously less instruction and value loading in the `fitler_next` version.

Could you please explain to me in detail what is the difference between these two implementations?

Comment: Does extracting the lambda function outside `filter_next` change the results? I imagine creating a new function every time has some(but probably insignificant in most cases) impact

Comment: "filter_next" has to call the lambda and has to transfer argument and return value to/from the lambda while the whole condition check remains in the generator expression for "tuple_comprehension_next".

Comment: @dumbPotato21 No the function is created once and the lambda expression is also evaluated once but calling it is slow.

Comment: Python is usually interpreted using CPython. This cause function calls to be slow because the interpreter need to do expensive operations internally though it as been [optimized over time](https://peps.python.org/pep-0590/). Typically, the overheads are in `PyFunction_Vectorcall` and `Py_CheckFunctionResult` (type checking is mandatory in CPython). If you care about such overheads, consider using Cython or PyPy. Compiled languages do not need that: functions can be inlined and there is (nearly) no runtime type checking.

Comment: For one thing, you have the additional overhead of a function cal on each iteration.

Comment: By the way, developers recently worked a lot so to speed up many parts of the interpreter (do not expect drastic changes though, its Python). So please consider trying CPython 3.11. The next dev version should also be a bit faster in some cases.

Comment: I wonder if *both* the generator and the filter call a function the performance will be similar. So `x for x in ... if func(x)` vs `filter(func, ...)`

Comment: Update: On Python 3.11, `filter()` is faster. My test (10 repeats, 1000 iterations per repeat) got me median values of "3.96" for generator, but "3.68" for filter. The mean does not differ much, though, "3.97" and "3.81", respectively.